# i want to get day name , day , month ,year from the date stored in String like "Wed, 27 feb 2013"

Tags: java, spring-mvc

"JAVA" i  stores Date in String like "wed, 27 Dec 2013" i want to extract day name , day , month, year from String date i am using spring MVC ,please guide me if anyone know  solution . or if there are other way then also please suggest me ..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it.  No JODA dependency:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
formatter.setLenient(false);
String dateStr = "Fri, 27 Dec 2013";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.instance();
calendar.setTime(date);
// Get values from calendar.
```

Comment: This fails because Dec 27 2013 is a Friday, not a Wednesday

Comment: thank you so much ..it worked .i set to to Fri and it ran properly. thank you again .

Comment: Good thing you set lenient to false.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
    String dateStr = "WED, 27 Dec 2013";
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    // Get values from calendar.
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));//1 indexed starting from Sunday
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));//0 indexed
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));//0 indexed
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Joda time.  It provides lots of methods for parsing dates, and obtaining data from them once they have been parsed.

Comment: This is trivial even with the standard SDK. Why the need for an external library which won't add any special benefit at this time? (Unless the poster will really be operating with dates)...

Comment: Because using anything with `java.util.Date` is a road to eventual pain so rather than starting with it and swapping over whenever you need to do real work you should just start with Joda and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the day of the week is inconsistent with the date represented, we will cut the string, and remove the day of the week, using `substring()`.

```
public static void main(String argsp[]) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    formatter.setLenient(false);
    String dateStr = "Wed, 27 Dec 2013";
    String sub = dateStr.substring(4);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(sub);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just fix the date String.

Comment: String dayNames[] = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays();  System.out.println("month is a" + monthNames[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]); above code gives me day name without using subString.